# Time Based Workflow - Records not getting added to the queue? or Queue limit exceeded?

Tags: governorlimits, time-dependent-workflow

What is the Maximum size of the Time Based Workflow Queue? I'm not able to find the record which are satisfying the rule criteria in the queue. The Workflow queue shows only 1000 records for a search criteria? Does it mean the maximum size is 1000 or still the search criteria has to be refined? Please help.

Answer (score 1):

https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=workflow_time_action_considerations.htm&language=en_US

Salesforce limits the number of time triggers an organization can execute per hour. If an organization exceeds the limits for its Edition, Salesforce defers the execution of the additional time triggers to the next hour. For example, if an Unlimited Edition organization has 1,200 time triggers scheduled to execute between 4:00 PM and 5:00 PM, Salesforce processes 1,000 time triggers between 4:00 PM and 5:00 PM and the remaining 200 time triggers between 5:00 PM and 6:00 PM.
US